# Get condition of a ConditionalExpression

Tags: conditional-statements, wolfram-mathematica

Given a conditional expression `cE = ConditionalExpression[ Value, Condition ]` how can I extract the Condition of `cE`?

I tried indexing, but that didn't help.

Comment: need a specific example. doesnt `ce[[2]]` work?

Comment: uh, yeah, you are right, it was in a nested expression and I exited one level too early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is interesting to give a cleaner version that you can use in more complex situations.

Consider [ConditionalExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) official documentation example

```
In[]:= ce = Integrate[x^n, {x, 0, 1}]
```

with the following output:

```
                               1
Out[]= ConditionalExpression[-----, Re[n] > -1]
                             1 + n
```

To extract the condition `Re[n] > -1` you can use:

```
In[]:= FirstCase[ce, ConditionalExpression[_, c_] :> c, Missing[], {0,-1}]
```

which prints:

```
Out[]= Re[n] > -1
```

In your comment you mentionned a nested expression, with the previous approach this will work too. For instance:

```
 In[]:= FirstCase[{{5, 6, ce, 1}}, ConditionalExpression[_, c_] :> c, Missing[], {0,-1}]
```

still returns

```
Out[]= Re[n] > -1
```

If the pattern is not found, the command gently returns `Missing[]`. For instance with `Sin[6]`:

```
In[]:= FirstCase[Sin[6], ConditionalExpression[_, c_] :> c, Missing[], {0,-1}]
```

the output is:

```
Out[]= Missing[]
```